# apply custom styles to anchor tag inside div from code behind

Tags: asp.net, css

here i want to apply custom styles to anchor tag inside div from code behind.
here is my code.here am applying several styles. font family is applying but font color and font size is not applying

```
<div id="sidenav" style="height:600px" runat="server">
            <ul id="abcd" runat="server" style="margin-top:30px;">
                <li>><a href="ViewEvents.aspx">Events</a></li>
                <li>><a href="PhotoGalleries.aspx">Photo Galleries</a></li>
                <li>><a href="InProgress.aspx">Location</a></li>
                <li>><a href="InProgress.aspx">Officials</a></li>
                <li>><a href="InProgress.aspx">Honours Board</a></li>
                <li>><a href="InProgress.aspx">History</a></li>
                <li>><a href="InProgress.aspx">Links</a></li>
                <li>><a href="InProgress.aspx">Site map</a></li>
                <li>><a href="InProgress.aspx">Help</a></li>                    
            </ul>
             <span id="myspan" runat="server">&nbsp;</span>
        </div>
 foreach (Control c in sidenav.Controls)
            {
                string abc = abcd.InnerText;
                abcd.InnerHtml = "<font ForeColor='" + objpage.NavigatioinTextcolor + "'>" + abc;
                //abc.Style.Add("color", objpage.NavigatioinTextcolor);
            }
                abcd.Style.Add("background-color", objpage.NavigationBackcolor);
                ////abcd.Style.Add("ForeColor", objpage.NavigatioinTextcolor);
                ////sidenav.Style.Add("color", objpage.NavigatioinTextcolor);
                ////sidenav.Style.Add("ForeColor", objpage.NavigatioinTextcolor);
                abcd.Style.Add("font-family", objpage.NavigatioinTextStyle);
                abcd.Style.Add("font-size", objpage.NavigatioinTextsize);
                abcd.Style.Add("font-size", string.Format(objpage.NavigatioinTextsize + "px"));
                abcd.Style.Add("style", "font-size:" + string.Format(objpage.NavigatioinTextsize + "px"));
```

Comment: would be great if you actually arrange your code before you put it up. removing your comments for example.

Answer (score 1):

use css for anchor tag

```
a
{
font family:cursive;
color :red;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create entire div into code-behind, by doing so, you can simply add styles fetched from database. Moreover, you can define the links in XML and progammatically build 'DIV' innerHTML in code-behind.

```
HtmlGenericControl div = new HtmlGenericControl();

div.InnerHtml += "<ul id='abcd' runat='server' style='margin-top:30px;'>";

div.InnerHtml += "<li><a herf='somepage.aspx' style='color:black;'>Events</a></li>";
```

Answer (score 0):

In css find ***sidenav*** add this

```
sidenav
{ 
   font-color: red;
   font-size:14px;
   font-family:Arial;

}
```

***note***:The font color, size and its family is up to you.